# Resposible font-size. Каким методом идти?

Tags: шрифты, css, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток и с наступившим!

Вопрос такой: на сайте есть информационные блоки с заголовками и некий текст. На мониторах отображается отлично (как и надо), а вот когда просматриваю с телефона или планшета - удовлетворение от шрифтов падает (блоки "едут") и т.д.

Сейчас решаю следующим образом:

1. Беру некую строку, которая, априори, должна занимать строго одну строку. Для неё применяю bigText (автоматическое определение максимального шрифта без переноса строки).
2. На load и resize вешаю функцию пересчета дочерних шрифтов относительно главного.

В правильном ли я направлении двигаюсь? Пробовал через [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)  - слишком много условий, и css теряет читабельность.

И в догоночку: что Вы думаете по поводу использования единиц измерения шрифта vw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, на десктопе всё грамотно и речь про мобильные устройства?
В мобильных устройствах не нужно событие resize (если точнее, оно есть, но его использовать, неверно, и не имеет смысла), есть `orientationchange`, но Вам думаю он тоже не нужен.

1) Поставьте фиксированный вьюпорт, например:

`<meta name=viewport content="width=640">`

2) Напишите всего 1 media-query под Ваш фиксированный вбюпорт:

`@media (max-width: 640px) { /* css here */ }`

И в нём отрегулируйте размер шрифта, при корректной вёрстке - это даст вам корректное отображение на всех устройствах.

Answer (score -1):

Первым делом добавь

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

В head и после используй [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal), код выше делает ширину сайта и все отображение сайта равным размерам устройства. Долго объяснять не буду, но если хочешь подробней, то почитай: http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport/

Насчет vw, то, я считаю, используй лучше тогда проценты, т.к. 1vw = 1%.

Comment: Зачем? Ну зачем `width=device-width`? Например, у iPhone4,4S это даст 320 пикселей и, конечно, всё поедет? Нужно указывать фиксированную ширину. А так же `initial-scale=1`, чтобы у пользователя был виден верхний левый угол десктопной верстки и ничего более? Initial-scale указывать не стоит, тогда сайтик сам "вмасштабируется" во вьюпорт (читай в экран)!